# Running android emulator from IntelliJ

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, intellij-idea

I am trying to emulate an Android device to test my app in IntelliJ using the command sudo ionic Cordova emulate Android. I keep getting the following error:

> (node:2808) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: No emulator images (avds) found.

Does anyone know how to fix this? The emulator images should exist because I am able to access them from the terminal.

Comment: Have you configured an avd ?

Comment: Yes, I have two avds configured - I can see them when I list using the CLI tools